# Automatically Pass Parent Pointer to its Variables?

Tags: c++

This is the functionality i currently have, i was wondering if there would be a way to be able to pass the parent pointer to all it's variables without having all the `= this`?

```
struct Location;

struct Parent
{
    std::vector<Location*> locations;
};

struct Location
{

    Location(Parent* p)
    {
        p->locations.push_back(this);
    }

};


struct SpecialParent : Parent
{

    Location a = this;
    Location b = this;
    Location c = this;
    Location zabaZoo = this;

    // etc

};
```

The point of this is so i can still do `specialParent->zabaZoo` but still batch process the locations for certain operations.

Comment: A better question. What is it you are trying to do mate? Whats the point of this?

Comment: I guess this is a real freaky use of the conversion constructor, because I don't think Parent should ever become Location.  I suggest making the Location constructor explicit and using `Location a(this);` so you don't need to question why the program compiles when you mistakenly used a Parent instead of a Location.

Comment: Also, I don't think there's anything wrong with explicitly passing references to members.  It shows dependencies which is mostly a good thing.

Comment: @stefaanv it's not used that often and location can be a private subclass of parent.

Comment: @nilo its for a sort of fake reflection, i'll update the code maybe to give a better idea.

Comment: Most of Qt's GUI classes have a constructor like that - its essentially used for automated memory management. Btw.: You are using a strange syntax here. (`Location a(this)` ) would be far more readable.

Comment: @MikeMB idk i really like having the "=", i find that makes it more readable (at least for me) in these sense you can see it is being assigned a value and can be aligned for visual aesthetic, though it is more verbose especially if there is more than one parameter, `Location a = Location(this);`.

Comment: I'd agree in cases like `int i=5`. Assignment usually means, that the left and right side are of the same type or that the right side can be converted to the left. Both id not the case. You are also not assigning `this` to `a`, but you use `this` to initialize an object of type `Location`. But in any case, use what suits you best or what your company's coding guidelines demand.

Comment: @user3901459 I wonder whether any of the answers was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
Location a = b = c = zabaZoo = this;
```

The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a `SpecialParent` constructor, and use assignment:

```
Location a, b, c, zabaZoo;

SpecialParent()
{
    a = b = c = zabaZoo = Location(this);
}
```

Comment: This requires a default constructor for `Location` :-/

Comment: and would require `Parent* parent;` in `Location` to be propagated in the assignment. Also feel this is the greater of two evils, as it repeats variable names twice, instead of once in my implementation. Though it does eliminate all the this's.

Comment: @Jarod42 Which might often be a good idea anyway, if nothing else just `Location() = default;`

Comment: @user3901459 At the time I wrote my answer we didn't have all information regarding what happened to the pointer in the `Location` constructor. I still feel we still don't, as we don't know what problem you are actually trying to solve (related reading: [What is the XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)).